# How to pass callback functions in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a simple class which `init` method takes an Int and a callback function.

```
class Timer {
  var timer = NSTimer()
  var handler: (Int) -> Void

  init(duration: Int, handler: (Int) -> Void) {
      self.duration = duration
      self.handler = handler
      self.start()
  }
  @objc func someMethod() {        
      self.handler(10)
  }
}
```

Then in the ViewController I have this:

```
var timer = Timer(duration: 5, handler: displayTimeRemaining)
func displayTimeRemaining(counter: Int) -> Void {
    println(counter)
}
```

This doesn't work, I get the following:

`'Int' is not a subtype of 'SecondViewController'`

**Edit 1: Adding full code.**

Timer.swift

```
import UIKit

class Timer {
    lazy var timer = NSTimer()
    var handler: (Int) -> Void

    let duration: Int
    var elapsedTime: Int = 0

    init(duration: Int, handler: (Int) -> Void) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.handler = handler
        self.start()
    }

    func start() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: Selector("tick"),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }

    func stop() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    func tick() {
        self.elapsedTime++

        self.handler(10)

        if self.elapsedTime == self.duration {
            self.stop()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var cycleCounter: UILabel!
    var number = 0

    var timer = Timer(duration: 5, handler: displayTimeRemaining)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnIncrementCycle_Click(sender: UIButton){
        cycleCounter.text = String(++number)
        println(number)
    }

    func displayTimeRemaining(counter: Int) -> Void {
        println(counter)
    }
}
```

I just started with Swift so I'm very green. How are you supposed to pass callbacks? I've looked at examples and this should be working I think. Is my class defined incorrectly for the way I'm passing the callback?

Thanks

Comment: Try passing `self.displayTimeRemaining`.  Swift might need an explicit reference to the instance method to disambiguate things; I know that's common in other languages.  (Sadly I don't have a mac handy so can't test if this fixes it for you.)

Comment: Didn't work. :( This is the error now: `'SecondViewController -> () -> SecondViewController!' does not have a member named 'displayTimeRemaining'`. I wonder if maybe I declared the function incorrectly inside the controller? I used the basic syntax you see in the code above.

Comment: should self.duration and self.start() in init() be timer.duration and timer.start()?

Comment: @davecom Not really. `start` and `duration` are a function and a property of the `Timer` class, not the `timer` instance of `NSTimer`. I didn't include these in the snippet here, but they are in my code. In any case, I don't think this would affect the fact that I can't pass a function to the class `init` without an error.

Comment: would you paste the full code around instantiating the Timer class variable?

Comment: @fernando No problem, was confused because you didn't include the rest of the code here.  In the future, on SO it's better if you include more relevant code rather than less because it leads to confusion like this.

Comment: @EranGloben I added the complete code now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, now with the full code I was able to replicate your issue. I'm not 100% sure what the cause is but I believe it has something to do with referencing a class method (*displayTimeRemaining*) before the class was instantiated. Here are a couple of ways around this:

Option 1: Declare the handler method outside of the *SecondViewController* class:

```
func displayTimeRemaining(counter: Int) -> Void {
  println(counter)
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {    

  // ...
  var timer = Timer(duration: 5, handler: displayTimeRemaining)
```

Option 2: Make *displayTimeRemaining* into a type method by adding the class keyword to function declaration.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  var timer: Timer = Timer(duration: 5, handler: SecondViewController.displayTimeRemaining)

  class func displayTimeRemaining(counter: Int) -> Void {
    println(counter)
  }
```

Option 3: I believe this will be the most inline with Swift's way of thinking - use a closure:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var timer: Timer = Timer(duration: 5) {
        println($0) //using Swift's anonymous method params
    }
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Option 2 is the one I went with and works great. Option 3 looks cleaner but it's giving me a compile error every time with XCode Beta 7. Not sure what the deal is there. That said, this option is better for simple callbacks, if it's something more involved Option 2 is better I think. Anyway, thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Yes excellent answer, I found opt 2 most helpful. For opt 3 wouldn't the closure need to be in the function call i.e. `Timer(duration: 5, handler: {println($0)} )`

Comment: Both will work. I believe that when a closure is the last parameter to a function, swift lets you drop the parameter and use the syntax I show above.

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        testFunc(index: 2, callback: { str in
            print(str)
        })

    }


    func testFunc(index index: Int, callback: (String) -> Void) {
        callback("The number is \(index)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the line:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
```

You cannot instantiate an NSTimer in this way. It has class methods that generate an object for you. The easiest way to get around the problem in this case is to make the definition lazy, like so:

```
lazy var timer = NSTimer()
```

In this way the value for timer won't actually be touched until the start method which sets it up properly. NOTE: There is probably a safer way to do this.

Comment: I tried this but is not making any difference. Maybe this fixes another issue. For now the main problem is when I initiate Time() in the ViewController, it won't take my custom function as the handler parameter.